# Since there is no Serial Port support in .NET 1.1, what is the workaround for working with serial ports?

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, legacy, zebra-printers

According to two sources (http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/224314-serial-communication-dll and http://www.innovatic.dk/knowledg/SerialCOM/SerialCOM.htm), .NET 1.1 has no Serial Port support.

The first URL says, ".NET Framework 2.0 also added the following namespaces:
System.IO.Ports  ->Supply the SerialPort class to implement serial port operation."

The second: ".Net 1.1 RTM (Release To Manufactoring) = No serial port support!"

So, since the project I'm enhancing is in .NET 1.1 on Visual Studio 2003 (in XP Mode on Windows 7), what recourse do I have to connect via the serial port to a belt printer (Zebra QL220) and send it some CPCL (print instructions)?

### UPDATE

It seems OpenNETCF may be the way to go, but I'm also not sure just how to use that...

Comment: Your most obvious recourse would be to stop using decade-old software.

Comment: Why are you doing .Net 1.1 stuff to begin with? I think everyone here will agree that 1.1 was deprecated long ago.

Comment: Good points, I'm sure, but it's not my call to make/easier said than done. The Symbol/Motorola device the app runs on only has .NET CF 1.0 on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use the OpenNETCF classes, which have a SerialPort class you can use.